# User can scroll when viewcontroller is presented modally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, modalviewcontroller

In my app, there is a big scrollView containing 5 view controllers.

There are 4 view controllers that display modally a view controller

With three of them, I can not scroll to other view controllers when the modal is presented (This is what I want). In these 3 view controller, I present the modal when the user taps a button

But in the fourth, I display a view controller modally when the user tap a cell from a UITableView, and when the modal is displayed, the user can scroll to the other view controllers. I don't want this to happen, how can I block that?

The only difference is that there is a prepare for segue in my code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.userTableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    GSBConversationViewController *destVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    GSBChatUsers *selectedUser =[chatUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *userName = selectedUser.name;

    NSLog(@"User selected: %@", userName);
    destVC.title=userName;

}
```

The code above is used to transmit the name displayed on the cell to the modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent user from touching through a view, you could add in your destVC class :

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}
```

or if use use .xib or storyboard, just select the destVC view and check `User Interaction Enabled` on the right column